# MudBlazor Table cannot bind to CurrentPage

Tags: blazor, mudblazor

I am able to bind the RowsPerPage but the [MudTable API](https://mudblazor.com/api/table#properties) doesn't seem to allow binding to CurrentPage. It that's not supported, is there an event I can trigger on page change?

```
<MudTable T="DataRow"
    Items="ViewModel.Rows"
    @bind-RowsPerPage="@ViewModel.RowsPerPage"
    @bind-CurrentPage="@ViewModel.CurrentPage"
```